# парсинг курса доллара и евро

Tags: python, парсер

Недавно начал изучать парсинг и наткнулся на проблему, на которую не смог найти ответа.
В общем у меня код получает только доллар, а нужно еще евро, можно ли как-то сделать, чтоб for прошел еще один раз больше предыдущего найденного значения?

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.fontanka.ru/currency.html"
HEADERS = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0", "accept": "*/*"}

def parse_rate():
    html = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS, params=None)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
    if html.status_code == 200:
        #items = soup.find_all("table", class_="J-af9")
        items = soup.find_all("tbody", class_="J-agb")
        rates = []
        for i in items:
            rates.append({
                "str": i.find("td", class_="J-d3").get_text(),
                "val": i.find("td", class_="J-agl").get_text()
            })
        print(rates)
    else:
        print("Ошибка: " + str(html.status_code))

parse_rate()
```

Выводит только: *[{'str': 'Доллар США', 'val': '70.97'}]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таблички лучше парсить через `Pandas`, а не "вручную":

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.fontanka.ru/currency.html"
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
print(df.loc[df['Валюта'].isin(['usd','eur']), ['Валюта','Курс']])
```

Вывод:

```
  Валюта   Курс
0    usd  70.97
1    eur  82.68
```

Вариант с выводом на печать в нужном формате:

```
df.loc[df['Валюта'].isin(['usd','eur']), ['Валюта.1','Курс']].apply(lambda x: print(f'{x[0]}: {x[1]}'), axis=1);
```

Вывод:

```
Доллар США: 71.06
Евро: 82.62
```

Comment: Выдает большое кол-во ошибок. lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py; lib\urllib\request.py; lib\http\client.py

Comment: Хм, а всё-таки конкретно что за ошибки? Это вы просто файлы указали, а не ошибки.

Comment: Тут много ошибок, все не вместится:
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)>
Вот последняя
pandas установил и вместе с ним cython

Comment: Ой, ну подружить библиотеки - это отдельное занятие, тут я сходу не помогу (  Лучше брать готовые сборки вроде `Anaconda`, потому что библиотеки должны быть совместимы между собой и с вашей версией питона, а не просто последние версии поставить и всё. Не всё так просто.

Comment: Решил проблему. Мало ли кто наткнется на этот вопрос или просто, выложу сюда.

import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

Comment: @PanSeek А может дело и не в версиях библиотек. Может вы через прокси ходите и она чудит :)  Проблемы с сертификатом - это что-то сетевое... Хотя что угодно может быть так то вообще. Ну, заработало - и хорошо.

Comment: Да, это сетевое, все было нормально раньше, впервые такое. А теперь вопрос по вашему ответу, возможно ли сделать такой вывод: "Доллар США: Цифры; Евро: Цифры". Там где "Цифры" то есть их курс, к примеру 71.2, а где ";" там перенос строки. Извиняюсь заранее за такое "обсуждение".

Comment: Добавил код. Но всё же лучше учите `Pandas`, он очень удобный для работы с табличными данными.

Comment: Хорошо, я буду его изучать) Спасибо огромное!

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` тоже учите, конечно, просто нет никакого смысла искать в `html` вручную названия классов элементов и т.д., если `Pandas` автоматически может вытащить все нужные таблицы. Да и с полученными данными гораздо удобнее работать потом.